# Trying to add ViewGroup into Linear layout of different activities

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-linearlayout, viewgroup

I'm trying to add ViewGroup into Linear layout after adding that into the previous activity's layout but getting the exception of IllegalStateException.

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

First Activity:

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdMobAdManager.InitialCallBack {

    LinearLayout layoutAdView;
    Button btnNext;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        AdMobAdManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        AdMobAdManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).initialCallBack(this);

        btnNext = findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        btnNext.setEnabled(false);
        layoutAdView = findViewById(R.id.layoutAdView);
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(TestActivity.this,TestActivity2.class));
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onInit() {
        btnNext.setEnabled(true);
        ViewGroup viewGroup = AdMobAdManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).loadBannerAd();
        layoutAdView.addView(viewGroup);
    }
}
```

Here is XML of TestActivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TestActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:text="Next"
        android:id="@+id/btnNext"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/layoutAdView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the Code of second activity:

```
public class TestActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    LinearLayout layoutAdView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test2);

        layoutAdView = findViewById(R.id.layoutAdView);
        addBanner();
    }

    private void addBanner() {
        ViewGroup viewGroup = AdMobAdManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).loadBannerAd();
        layoutAdView.addView(viewGroup);
    }
}
```

Here is XML of second Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TestActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/layoutAdView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In general, I'm loading Admob banner ad into the first Activity and trying to add that banner into the second activity.

Here is code of requesting to load banner:

```
public class AdMobAdManager {
    private static AdMobAdManager ourInstance;

    private Context context;

    private AdView bannerAdView;

    private boolean isInitialised, isInitialising;

    private InitialCallBack initialCallBack;

    public synchronized static AdMobAdManager getInstance(Context context) {
        if (ourInstance == null) {
            ourInstance = new AdMobAdManager(context);
        }
        return ourInstance;
    }

    private AdMobAdManager(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        isInitialising = true;
        MobileAds.initialize(context, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
                Log.v("TAG_ADMOB","onInitializationComplete");
                isInitialising = false;
                isInitialised = true;

                if (initialCallBack != null){
                    initialCallBack.onInit();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void initialCallBack(InitialCallBack initialCallBack){
        this.initialCallBack = initialCallBack;
        if (isInitialised()){
            initialCallBack.onInit();
        }
    }
    public boolean isInitialised() {
        return isInitialised;
    }

    public boolean isInitialising() {
        return isInitialising;
    }

    public AdView loadBannerAd(){
        if (bannerAdView == null){
            bannerAdView = new AdView(context);
            bannerAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
            bannerAdView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");
            bannerAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener());
            bannerAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        }else {
            bannerAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        }
        return bannerAdView;
    }

    public interface  InitialCallBack{
        void onInit();
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me how what's wrong in this code and how can I resolve it?